# In TFJS, model.predict() is undefined

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow.js

I used the Keras model I made by converting it to tensorflow.js. I called the model in js. I tried to predict the new value to the model. However, **`model.predict() is undefined`**.
The value of `model.predict().dataSync()[0]` is also undefined.

If you look at the `model.summary()` in js, you can see that it is a model that I made. I've put in tensor and [[]] in `predict()` arg'. It was all to no avail.

Attached is my model and the corresponding partial code below. I wish you could help me. If you need more code, please leave a comment. Thank you for your help.

##### model.json

```js
{"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v2.4.0", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v3.8.0", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "2.4.0", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Sequential", "config": {"name": "sequential_2", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 34], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "dense_5_input"}}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_5", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 256, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_6", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 128, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_7", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 1000, "activation": "softmax", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}}]}}, "training_config": {"loss": "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", "metrics": [[{"class_name": "MeanMetricWrapper", "config": {"name": "accuracy", "dtype": "float32", "fn": "sparse_categorical_accuracy"}}]], "weighted_metrics": null, "loss_weights": null, "optimizer_config": {"class_name": "Adam", "config": {"name": "Adam", "learning_rate": 0.0010000000474974513, "decay": 0.0, "beta_1": 0.8999999761581421, "beta_2": 0.9990000128746033, "epsilon": 1e-07, "amsgrad": false}}}}, "weightsManifest": [{"paths": ["group1-shard1of1.bin"], "weights": [{"name": "dense_5/kernel", "shape": [34, 256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_5/bias", "shape": [256], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_6/kernel", "shape": [256, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_6/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_7/kernel", "shape": [128, 1000], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_7/bias", "shape": [1000], "dtype": "float32"}]}]}
```

##### predictPose

```js
const predictPose = (arr) => {
    // Arr is array with 34 numbers as elements.
    // ex) [234,123,324,.....,222]
    const prediction, model;
    model = loadModel();
    const p = async () => {
      prediction = model().predict([arr]).dataSync()[0];
      //pedicttion = model().predict(tf.tensor([arr])).dataSync()[0];
    };
    console.log(prediction); // The result is undefined.
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`const prediction, model;` will throw an error actually, you can't assign `const` to nothing, you can do that for `let` in this case as you intend to reassign the variable name later on but its unnecessary. Another issue is that you aren't even loading in any model. Based on your `model.json` you would need to use [tf.loadLayersModel()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel). The code below should work.

```js
const predictPose = async (arr) => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel("path to model.json");
    const prediction = model.predict([arr]).dataSync()[0];
    console.log(prediction);
};
```